# Error 400 when running Visual Studio 2019 React template

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio, error-handling

I created an ASP NET Core application with React template and I didnt change anything there. When I am starting it I am getting error 400 in browser. There are no errors in Output window.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the address which your application starts e.g. https://localhost:44371/ and your app loads there, then you have cache issue or some conflict.

I have cleaned my browser cache from here:

**chrome://settings/clearBrowserData?search=cache**

Good idea is to set a proper time period, otherwise you will erase cookies that you don't need to. [image]

Hope this helps. It did in my case.